# How to synchronize servlet writes to a common xml file resource without transformer exceptions

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to write a servlet that must update an xml file in my web-apps folder, every time a client requests the update. But since the file is a common resource I get the following erron on mvn:jetty server.
I get  a Transformer exception which basically says the file is not found because the requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open. I believe this is a windows system message to ensure thread safety.

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\User
s\Anubhav\workspace2\blogping-dist (eng)\dreamapp\src\main\webapp\xyz.xml (T
he requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section                       
open)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutpu
tHandler(TransformerImpl.java:489)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transfor
m(TransformerImpl.java:298)
```

Any suggestions to help synchronize access to it?

I looked up transformer objects bottlenecks...but didnt find much on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure you close the stream to the file (`fileOutputStream.close()`)
- Synchronize writes. Use `synchronized(lockObject)` or [`lock.lock()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

I would question if the design of the app is good if writes to a common file are required on each request. This is a potential bottleneck and you should try to avoid it. For example consider a transactional database instead of a file.

Comment: +1 Forcing HTTP requests to proceed serially instead of in parallel is a recipe for disaster unless you'll only ever have five users.

Comment: indeed. If this does not happen for every request, it might be fine. But otherwise a transactional database should be considered

Comment: Thanks Bozho. But I must update an xml file that must be accessible to a client program reflecting the changes requested. And this xml file is common to all clients who may wish to see it. I tried [http://serghei.net/docs/programming/java/devel%20java%20enterprise%20apps/ch07/07-12.html]. But still doesnt work.

Comment: I tried it on linux...no issues at all...the problem is only with windows